# How to display two currency in magento cart

Tags: magento

I want to display two currencies in Magento's cart and invoice. I have make it in product page by this code

```
<div class="currency">
<?php if( Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode() == 'USD'): ?>
<span class="price">(<?php echo round(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert( $_product->getFinalPrice(), 'USD', 'AUD'), 2 ); ?>) AUD</span>
<?php else: ?>
<span class="price">(<?php echo round(Mage::helper('di`enter code here`rectory')->currencyConvert( $_product->getFinalPrice(), 'AUD', 'USD'), 2 ); ?>) USD</span>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

and now I want to display this in the email invoice.

Answer (score 0):

in the email template ti has this line

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

looking up sales layouts we find app\design\frontend[package][theme]\layout\sales.xml

from there you can see the .phtml files used to render the items section of the email, edit the ones you need, keep in mind that these are also used on the front end.

if you want to separate the .phtml files so that the frontend and email template can use different files, copy/paste/rename `sales_email_order_items` in the .xml file and change the `template=` parts to the new templates, be sure that in your email template you change the handle stated above to what you renamed the layout to otherwise it'll use the original one.

your code should work fine, you may just need to change `$_product->getFinalPrice()` if it doesn't work and $_product may not be in the template or be a different class since your dealing with the the collection that deals with sales_flat_order rather than catalog_product